# Leaflet resizes geoJson layer on update

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

I need to update leaflet map with aggregated data on zoom change, so that when user changes the zoom, aggregation is performed on the backend and the data is sent to the map.

I have a problem with displaying the data from backend, because when data is changed, map isn't updated and then if I pan, the map is updated, but the layer with markers is shifted and resized to fit the viewport, so markers are not in their actual coordinates (its better explained by the attached images).

Initial map state:
[image: Initial state]

After zoom and update (map didn't detect changes):
[image: After zoom and update]

After small pan (map detected changes, but the geoJson layer is shifted and resized):
[image: After small pan]

Code for updating the map (it removes the old geoJson layer and creates the new one to draw):

```
refreshMap(data) {
    if (this.layer) {
        this.layer.clearLayers();
    }

    let pointToLayer = (feature, latlng) => {
        let radius = 10 + Math.log2(feature.properties.count);
        let circleMarker = L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius,
            fillColor: uiSettings.map.cluster.fillColor,
            fillOpacity: uiSettings.map.cluster.fillOpacity,
            color: uiSettings.map.cluster.strokeColor,
            weight: uiSettings.map.cluster.strokeWeight,
            opacity: uiSettings.map.cluster.strokeOpacity,
        });
        circleMarker.bindTooltip(`${feature.properties.count}`, { permanent: true });
        return circleMarker;
    };

    this.layer = L.geoJSON(data, { pointToLayer });
    this.layer.addTo(this.map);
}
```

I wasn't able to google similar cases, so maybe somebody had the problem with this or can say what can cause it?

Comment: What's your Leaflet version? Are there any errors in the browser's dev console? Can you publish a _complete_, _reproducible_ example?

Comment: @IvanSanchez My leaflet version is 1.0.1, there are no errors in the console, I'll need some time to publish  an example, so I'll ping you when it'll be ready, thanks for involvement)

Comment: Your tooltips look at the correct position, but not your Circle Markers. Are you using Canvas or SVG?

Comment: @ghybs, yes, I forgot to mention it, I'm using SVG

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I've run into something similar (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716498)